# vba conditional formating based on a different column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have range "A1: B10".
I want to apply conditional formatting to range A1:A10 such that if cell B in that row contains text "ok" then apply some format to cell A in that row.

Example:

```
A        B
text    ok
text    other text
text    ok
```

cells A1 and A3 will be formatted by the conditional formatting setting.
I understand how to use FormatConditions.Add when it comes to testing the same cells which I want to format but not when it is based to a condition in other cells.

Thanks

Comment: You know you don't need VBA for this, right? Conditional formatting knows this by default, so why not just record a macro while setting it up?

Comment: I gave a simple example just to understand how to use formatConditions. In my macro the conditions are much more complicated and recording gives me too much mess

Answer (score 0):

To base the conditional formatting on other cells, reference the other cells in the formula.

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(""ok"", B1)))"
```

The Offset function works in the formula, too.

```
Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OFFSET(A1, 0, 1)="ok""
```

Answer (score 0):

When referencing cells other then the one being formatted, pay attention to the absolute-relative references.

Also note the double quotes escaping the quotation mark.

```
Range("A1:B3").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B1=""ok"""
```